# How can I replace the code with preg_replace_callback()? (/e)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

```
$in = '(&lt;(/?(?:strong|p|em|a|ol|ul|li|img|iframe)\b.*?)&gt;)ie';

$contenu = preg_replace($in, "'<'.html_entity_decode('$1',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8').'>'", $contenu);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: How can I replace the code with preg_replace_callback()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern = '~&lt;(/?(?:strong|p|em|a|ol|ul|li|img|iframe)\b.*?)&gt;~is';

$contenu = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    return '<' . html_entity_decode($m[1], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF_8') . '>'; }, $contenu);
```